# UI only updating once when adding new item to ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I came across a really strange error an hour ago and couldn't solve it. My code contain an ObservableCollection which is bound to my View (Listview). I can add a new item to my database and it will be added to my ObservableCollection too. The UI is updating properly but only the FIRST time. If I add a second item it will appear inside my database and also my collection but my UI doesn't update anymore. Can anyone check my code to see if there is something wrong?

View:

```
<ListView Name="Departments_Listview" ItemsSource="{Binding Departments, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" SelectedItem="{Binding YourSelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}" Height="346">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Department" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Department}"/>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

ViewModel

```
using Autofac;
using Calendar.Commands;
using Calendar.Database.Entities;
using Calendar.Database.Repositories;
using Calendar.Helper_Classes;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows;

namespace Calendar.ViewModels
{
    public class DepartmentViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        private RelayCommand command;
        private DepartmentEntity _yourSelectedItem;
        ObservableCollection<DepartmentEntity> _Departments = new ObservableCollection<DepartmentEntity>();
        public DepartmentViewModel()
        {
        }
        public ObservableCollection<DepartmentEntity> Departments
        {
            get
            {
                var container = ContainerConfig.Configure();
                using (var scope = container.BeginLifetimeScope())
                {
                    var test = scope.Resolve<IDepartmentRepository>();
                    _Departments = test.GetAll().ToObservable();
                }
                return _Departments;
            }
            set
            {
                _Departments = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Departments");
            }
        }

        private string department;

        public string Department
        {
            get { return department; }
            set
            {
                department = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Department");
            }
        }
        public DepartmentEntity YourSelectedItem
        {
            get
            {
                return _yourSelectedItem;
            }
            set
            {
                if (value != null)
                {
                    Department = value.Department;
                }
                _yourSelectedItem = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("YourSelectedItem");
            }
        }
        private void NewDepartment()
        {
            var container = ContainerConfig.Configure();
            using (var scope = container.BeginLifetimeScope())
            {
                var NewDepartment = scope.Resolve<IDepartmentRepository>();
                DepartmentEntity newDepartment = new DepartmentEntity
                {
                    Department = "Bitte ändern"
                };
                NewDepartment.Add(newDepartment);
                int DepartmentId = NewDepartment.Count();
                _Departments.Add(
                    new DepartmentEntity()
                    {
                        Id = DepartmentId,
                        Department = "Bitte ändern"
                    });
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add `NotifyPropertyChanged("Departments");` after adding the new item, e.g. after

```cs
 _Departments.Add(
     new DepartmentEntity()
     {
         Id = DepartmentId,
         Department = "Bitte ändern"
     });
```

It allows UI to understand, that `Departments` property was updated.
You can also think about getting rid of this code in `Departments` getter

```cs
var container = ContainerConfig.Configure();
using (var scope = container.BeginLifetimeScope())
{
      var test = scope.Resolve<IDepartmentRepository>();
      _Departments = test.GetAll().ToObservable();
}
```

since you already added new item to `_Departments` backing field

Comment: I thought that ObservableCollection implements auto notification if an item is added or removed?

Any it worked, thanks a lot!

Comment: Try to check without `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` in `ItemsSource` binding

Comment: Without your solution and removed UpdateSourceTrigger it's working too ... really strange, nearly sure I tried this approach before :/ Whatever, your comment helped me to solve the problem!